# How can I enable a Node.js Intellisense in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, ide, intellisense, hint

How can I enable a Node.js Intellisense in VS Code?

For instance, I am aware of a constant in Node.js `__dirname`, but when I try to type `__dir` in VS Code I am not getting any suggestions, while I would expect to see the `__dirname` as a suggestion.

[image]

What can I do about it? Maybe I should install a plugin?

Here is the version of VS Code I am using:

```
Version: 1.33.1 (user setup)
Commit: 51b0b28134d51361cf996d2f0a1c698247aeabd8
Date: 2019-04-11T08:27:14.102Z
Electron: 3.1.6
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't install any extensions, I am using version 1.33.1, On my side, working suggestion with `__dir`, what is your version?

Comment: What is your node version / OS?

Comment: Do you have Node installed locally? You should have Node installed locally so you can also have access to the run time debugger.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There was some time while back that:

```
npm install node
```

in the project root folder was enough for vscode (at least for my case) to give me intellisense for node. Now I need to do the following:

```
npm install @types/node
```

again in the project folder.
[Also the same solution seems to be suggested from vs code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_why-am-i-not-seeing-method-and-variable-suggestions) .

Comment: Thanks! I was experiencing the same thing and finally found this perfect solution.

Comment: Here from 2022, thank you so much! This solution is still working :)!

Comment: Yay, here in 2023 and this seemed to work for me.

Comment: why do you need `npm install node`?